# Parse Google Translate JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, json, translate

What is the best way to Parse the JSON from Google Translate.

So far I have:

```
NSString *urlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=%@&target=%@&q=%@",
                      key, target, selectedWord];

NSLog(@"%@", urlText);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlText];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The result is:

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "Provincial capital",
     "detectedSourceLanguage": "de"
   }
  ]
 }
```

}

I then :

```
if(data != nil){
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization
                                    JSONObjectWithData:data
                                    options:kNilOptions
                                    error:&error];
NSArray *dataObj = dic[@"data"];

NSLog(@"%@", dataObj);
}
else {
NSLog(@"ERR");
}
```

Which produces:

```
{
translations =     (
            {
        detectedSourceLanguage = de;
        translatedText = "Provincial capital";
    }
);
}
```

How would I then go about getting the "de" from detectedSourceLanguage and "Provincial capital" from translatedText?
I've tried creating a second array:

```
NSArray *arr2 = [dataObj valueForKey:@"detectedSourceLanguage"];
```

without success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `dic[@"data"];` gives you a dictionary, not an array. So you need:

```
NSDictionary *data = dic[@"data"];
```

Now you need the translations array:

```
NSArray *translations = data[@"translations"];
```

That is an array of dictionaries:

```
for (NSDictionary *translation in translations) {
    NSString *detectedLanguage = translation[@"detectedSourceLanguage"];
    NSString *translatedText = translation[@"translatedText"];
}
```

Just break the problem down one step at a time to get to the data you need.

Comment: Works a charm. Thank you.