# JSON to parse google translate API

Tags: ios, google-app-engine

I am trying to parse data for google translate. In viewdidload, I wrote the following code.

```
NSString * target = @"ja";
NSString * source = @"en";
NSString *textEscaped = @"Hi, How are u";
NSString *ke=@"My_key";
NSString * urlText =[NSString 
key=%@&source=%@&format=text&target=%@&q=%@",ke,source,target,textEscaped];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlText];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response 
error:&error];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

I compared my code with different sources and my API is also activated but I am getting nothing in result string. Its bill. Why?

Comment: Have you passed NSString *ke=@"My_key"; check and replace it with real key. Otherwise you can Afnetworking for this one

Comment: Yes, I replaced it with real key. but I do not know why NSData is always Nill.

Comment: Can you please post whole code on pastie so i can check it?

Comment: Log the `error` variable after calling `sendSynchronousRequest`.

Comment: This is the only code in viewdidload. I am trying this for hours and tried in many different ways but in all cases, I am getting null data. It's very strange. This code I referred from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505222/parse-google-translate-json-in-ios here.

Comment: By Loging error, I get this. Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x165b48a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1668d630 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}

Comment: It seems like you have not mentioned url:--https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2

Comment: I mentioned and I found the problem. I added this line     NSString *text = [textEscaped stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and replaced textEscaped with text. The error disappears, now I get this error. message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." My API is activated and billing account is also activated.

Comment: Please try to make string like this:-- NSString *urlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=%@&target=%@&q=%@", key, target, selectedWord];

Comment: Can anybody tell me why google Developer console is inactive. I made account on 18 july, filled billing information and also used online Translate API on developers console, but it is still inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Your url like this:

```
[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2key=%@&target=%@&q=%@",key, target, selectedWord];
```